# Centering title when next to toolbar

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a title bar with a nice centered title and a toolbar next to it. The issue I'm having is that as the toolbar grows, the title move further and further off center (and is never really centered to begin with). I've been monkeying with this for a while, tried a few searches, but can't seem to find an answer. Can someone with a bit more css experience throw me a bone please?

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>
        Section Title
    </span>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>Remove</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div { background:red;overflow:hidden;  text-align: center; }

span a {
    background:#222;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;

    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding:5px 10px
}

.toolbar {
    float: right;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/scottvossen/cePe3/124/

Comment: Looks centered to me.

Comment: The prompt asking you to post code in your question is there for a reason. Don't cheat around it

Comment: Yeah finally figured out it was wanting code not just wanting the link in a code block. My bad.. don't post things often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use `position: relative` on the outer div and `position: absolute` on the inner div. You can learn more about positioning divs [here](http://wickham43.net/divboxes.php).

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pztzpt6y/). I also centered the text vertically.

HTML

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="centeroutline">
        <div id="centertext">
        Section Title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div id="buttons">        
            <button>Add</button>
            <button>Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#background { 
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;  
    text-align: center; 
    height:26px;
    width:auto;
}

#buttons{
    position:relative;
}

#centeroutline {
    color:#fff;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}

#centertext{
    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding:5px 10px;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.toolbar {
    right:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add the code in the answer. If fiddle goes down, the code will still be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Great answer! I got to this same conclusion after working with the previous answer. This is more succinct so you get it!.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: relative` to the containing `div`. Then absolute position the toolbar in the corner.

```
div{
  position: relative
}

.toolbar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jth2013/cePe3/126/)**